# Themes for angular 2 application

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I want to provide themes functionality using angular material 2. Can anyone provide an example how to do that? I tried using material 2 themes but it didn't work.

Comment: in material2 you can define your own theme, just follow theme guid2 of material 2. https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md

Answer (score 1):

Guide for Angular CLI:

choose the theme you wanna use: indigo-pink, deeppurple-amber, pink-bluegrey, purple-green.

**styles.css**

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.c‌​ss';
```

**styles.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink';
```

create your own theme https://youtu.be/0q9FOeEELPY?t=17m6s

and here https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md#defining-a-custom-theme

Answer (score 1):

You might need to crate your custom theme `theme.scss`:

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';

@include md-core();

$primary: md-palette($md-indigo);
$accent:  md-palette($md-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$warn:    md-palette($md-red);

$app-theme: md-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);
```

Put it in your `assets` folder

Then in `styles.scss` just import that:

```
@import '/assets/theme';
```

Also you can choose any existing themes if you look in to `node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\prebuilt\` just by referencing one in `styles.scss` e.g:

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber';
```

For more details see [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) and [aterial2-app](https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app).

Answer (score 1):

here the steps:

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-Material

however you should to resolve the issue of theming by :

Looks like they've changed the Github build of Material. Instead of

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';
```

Try this out:

```
@import '~@angular/material/_theming.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG did that. You can check their repo.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng

And this is live site

http://primefaces.org/primeng